# Excluding primary key in Django dumpdata with natural keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do you exclude the primary key from the JSON produced by Django's dumpdata when natural keys are enabled?

I've constructed a record that I'd like to "export" so others can use it as a template, by loading it into a separate databases with the same schema without conflicting with other records in the same model.

As I understand Django's support for natural keys, this seems like what NKs were designed to do. My record has a unique `name` field, which is also used as the natural key.

So when I run:

```
from django.core import serializers
from myapp.models import MyModel
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=123)
serializers.serialize('json', [obj], indent=4, use_natural_keys=True)
```

I would expect an output something like:

```
[
    {
        "model": "myapp.mymodel", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "foo", 
            "create_date": "2011-09-22 12:00:00", 
            "create_user": [
                "someusername"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

which I could then load into another database, using loaddata, expecting it to be dynamically assigned a new primary key. Note, that my "create_user" field is a FK to Django's auth.User model, which supports natural keys, and it output as its natural key instead of the integer primary key.

However, what's generated is actually:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 123,
        "model": "myapp.mymodel", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "foo", 
            "create_date": "2011-09-22 12:00:00", 
            "create_user": [
                "someusername"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

which will clearly conflict with and overwrite any existing record with primary key 123.

What's the best way to fix this? I don't want to retroactively change all the auto-generated primary key integer fields to whatever the equivalent natural keys are, since that would cause a performance hit as well as be labor intensive.

Edit: This seems to be [a bug](http://markmail.org/message/og5ch7ol3l5tg3mm) that was [reported](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13252)...2 years ago...and has largely been ignored...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with `json` is that you can't omit the `pk` field since it will be required upon loading of the fixture data again. If not existing, json will fail with

```
$ python manage.py loaddata some_data.json
[...]
File ".../django/core/serializers/python.py", line 85, in Deserializer
data = {Model._meta.pk.attname : Model._meta.pk.to_python(d["pk"])}
KeyError: 'pk'
```

As pointed out in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499898/django-create-fixtures-without-specifying-a-primary-key), you can use `yaml` or `xml` if you really want to omit the `pk` attribute *OR* just replace the primary key value with `null`.

```
import re
from django.core import serializers

some_objects = MyClass.objects.all()
s = serializers.serialize('json', some_objects, use_natural_keys=True)
# Replace id values with null - adjust the regex to your needs
s = re.sub('"pk": [0-9]{1,19}', '"pk": null', s)
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I discovered myself.

Comment: It seems you can omit the `pk` field even in json now.

Comment: Brilliant solution, thanks - I just edited the regex to encompass a bigauto pk, because I was getting exported results like `"pk": null134,`

Answer (score 12):

Updating the answer for anyone coming across this in 2018 and beyond.

There is a way to omit the primary key through the use of natural keys and unique_together method. Taken from the [Django documentation on serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#natural-keys):

You can use this command to test :

```sh
python manage.py dumpdata app.model --pks 1,2,3 --indent 4 --natural-primary --natural-foreign > dumpdata.json ;
```

**Serialization of natural keys**

So how do you get Django to emit a natural key when serializing an object? Firstly, you need to add another method – this time to the model itself:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthdate = models.DateField()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('first_name', 'last_name'),)
```

That method should always return a natural key tuple – in this example, (first name, last name). Then, when you call `serializers.serialize()`, you provide `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` or `use_natural_primary_keys=True` arguments:

```py
serializers.serialize('json', [book1, book2], indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

When `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` is specified, Django will use the `natural_key()` method to serialize any foreign key reference to objects of the type that defines the method.

When `use_natural_primary_keys=True` is specified, Django will not provide the primary key in the serialized data of this object since it can be calculated during deserialization:

```
    {
        "model": "store.person",
        "fields": {
            "first_name": "Douglas",
            "last_name": "Adams",
            "birth_date": "1952-03-11",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Override the `Serializer` class in a separate module:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JsonSerializer

class Serializer(JsonSerializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self.objects.append({
            "model"  : smart_unicode(obj._meta),
            "fields" : self._current, 
            # Original method adds the pk here
        })
        self._current = None
```

Register it in Django:

```
serializers.register_serializer("json_no_pk", "path.to.module.with.custom.serializer")
```

Add use it:

```
serializers.serialize('json_no_pk', [obj], indent=4, use_natural_keys=True)
```

Comment: I'd prefer this solution, however deserialization fails without pk value. You should set ``"pk": None,`` rather then deleting the whole field