# How to use Django model functions

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an application with a few models listed below:

```
devices.Device
buildings.Building
buildings.Stack
buildings.Switch
rooms.Room
```

In my program, I accept a `CSV` file with data. Then I parse it into `JSON` representing each model and use `get_or_create()` to add the data into the database. Here is an example:

```
                obj, created = Building.objects.get_or_create(
                    name=entry["fields"]["name"],
                    number=entry["fields"]["number"])
                if created:
                    output += "Building was created!\n"
                else:
                    output += "Building already exists!\n"
```

And the above is working well. However, I tried the code below, and could not get it to work:

```
                obj, created = Switch.objects.get_or_create(
                    stack=entry["fields"]["stack"],
                    number=entry["fields"]["number"],
                    ip=entry["fields"]["ip"],
                    num_ports=entry["fields"]["num_ports"])
                if created:
                    output += "Switch was created!\n"
                else:
                    output += "Switch already exists!\n"
```

Which causes this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/cutsheets/cutsheets/views.py" in import_data
  156.             output = process_xls_data(temp_dir)
File "/opt/cutsheets/cutsheets/views.py" in process_xls_data
  113.                     obj, created = Switch.objects.get_or_create(

Exception Type: NameError at /import
Exception Value: global name 'Switch' is not defined
```

I suspect that it has to do with the way the models are constructed (which wasn't done by me). Could anyone suggest how to modify the above code so I could insert Switches and Stacks using `get_or_create()`?

And, here is stack and switch from /buildings/models.py:

```
class Switch(models.Model):
stack = models.ForeignKey(Stack, null=True, related_name='switches')
number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
ip = models.IPAddressField()
num_ports = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.number)

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('buildings.views.switch', (self.stack.building.number, self.stack.number, self.number))


class Stack(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name='stacks')
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    num_switches = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.number)

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('buildings.views.stack', (self.building.number, self.number))
```

Comment: Please post the complete `Switch` and `Stack` models and, if you encounter an actual python error, the traceback.

Comment: In your query, `num_ports=["fields"]["num_ports"]` You *forgot* `entry` - It should be `num_ports= entry["fields"]["num_ports"]`

Comment: You said the code don't work, but you didn't said what's the error you got from running that snippet of code. Plese be more specific in your question.

Comment: Okay, I made those edits

Comment: Seems to me like you haven't imported the `Switch` class.

Comment: So should `from buildings.models import Building` become `from buildings.models import Building, Switch, Stack`?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to import Switch and Stack. I changed:

`from buildings.models import Building`
to `from buildings.models import Building, Switch, Stack`